# SQL Server rounds seconds to hours randomly

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I'm executing the following query.

```
declare @Offset as int = 3600
declare @Now as datetime = getdate()
declare @Then as datetime = dateadd(ss, @Offset, @Now)
declare @Diff as int = datediff(hh, @Now, @Then)
select @Now, @Then, @Diff
```

The objective is to examine how the server handles conversion to full hours given different number of seconds. For offset 3600, it should be 1 (which is confirmed). For 3000 it should be 0 or 1 (depending on whether it rounds or floors). According to the result, it is 0.

I tried 3599 expecting to get 0 but, to my surprise, I got 1. So I started to decrease gradually to find the threshold. Eventually, I reached 3000 and got 1! It was 0 before...

Then, I retried the exercise with 2400, getting 0. Iteratively lowering by about 20 (i.e. 2500, 2480, 2460, 2440, 2420) I repeatedly got 1. Finally, I reached 2400 and this time, it produced 1!

It seems that I gradually affect how the hour count is rounded, which sounds insane technically speaking. Still, I can't argue with the reality - it does happen.

What is the actual reason for the observed phenomenon?

Comment: declare @Now as datetime2 = getdate();  datetime2 surely. datetime was deprecated a decade ago. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: 2 point : `#1:-` `getdate()` returns date & time. `#2:-` `datediff(hour, ...)` returns the different between 2 time by taking the hour of one and subtract the other. It return 1 does not means the time different is 60 minutes. Try `datediff(hour, '01:59', '02:01')`, it gives you one. `2 - 1 = 1`

Comment: Have you read the docs? You don't need to research or re-discover this, it is by design

Comment: for those who want to see a reproduction of this: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7674b40db318bbe2f71d1158fc1abaae)   Please run it, look at the output, and re-run it to see a different output.

Comment: @MitchWheat In this case it is appropriate to use `DateTime` because that is the type that is returned from [`GetDate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) Instead of `DateTime2`, In a cloud based or distributed solution I would strongly encourage devs to adopt `DateTimeOffset` and of course `SysDateTimeOffset()` instead of `DateTime` and `GetDate()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)**
> This function returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

The important phrase here is ***specified datepart boundaries crossed***. It is **NOT** a measure of the absolute elapsed time between two values.

So A `DATEDIFF` of `hour` between two `DateTime` values (or `DateTime2`, or `DateTimeOffset`) will *ONLY* look at the *LEFT* part of the value up to the *hours* part of the date. Truncating the value to the hours, the seconds is removed for the purpose of the comparison.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2022-01-01 14:59:00', '2022-01-01 15:01')     --> 1
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2022-01-01 14:01:00', '2022-01-01 14:59')     --> 0     
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2022-01-01 13:59:59', '2022-01-01 15:00:59')  --> 2
```

> The objective is to examine how the server handles conversion to full hours given different number of seconds. For offset 3600, it should be 1 (which is confirmed). For 3000 it should be 0 or 1 (depending on whether it rounds or floors)

**There is no *rounding* going on here at all, *it is a simple truncation*.** This means that every second in between your tests, because you are using `GetDate()` the seconds component of the time during execution is advancing, which is reducing the number of seconds that is required to push the value you are evaluating *into* the next *hour*.

Effectively this is a *Floor*, but the original values are *floored* first, before the comparison. It is not a *rounding* or *floor* of the total time between the two values, perhaps this is the most significant factor!

There is also nothing *random* about the output at all! Every time you re-run your query, some seconds have changed so the output will as well. ***DO NOT** use 'GetDate()' as a proof for testing any of the date functions in SQL* as that makes your test and the results bound to that specific point in time! (The test will be non-repeatable)

For this reason, if you need to calculate the *Total Elapsed Hours* between two times, you will need to use the next significant date part to the right and adjust your results: (for `hour`, then next most significant is `minute`)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '2022-01-01 14:59:00', '2022-01-01 15:01') / 60.0     --> 0.033333
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '2022-01-01 14:01:00', '2022-01-01 14:59') / 60.0     --> 0.966666     
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '2022-01-01 13:59:59', '2022-01-01 15:00:59') / 60.0  --> 1.016666
```

How you deal with *rounding* in this case becomes entirely up to you.

[This query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=debda10b5ebe7282f53d6215b9576ec1) evaluates different combinations of `@Now` and `@Offset` to compute the `@Diff` and `@Then`:

```
WITH Times AS (
    SELECT [Now]=CAST('2022-07-01 14:00' as datetime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Now]=CAST('2022-07-01 14:30' as datetime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Now]=CAST('2022-07-01 14:45' as datetime)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Now]=CAST('2022-07-01 14:55' as datetime)
)
, Interval as (
    SELECT offset = 3600
    UNION ALL
    SELECT offset = o.offset - 300
    FROM Interval o
    WHERE o.offset > 0
)
SELECT 
     [Now], [offset], [Then], [Diff]
FROM Times
CROSS JOIN Interval
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [Then] = dateadd(ss, Offset, [Now])) as func1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Diff = datediff(hh, [Now], [Then])) as func2
```

| Now | Offset | Then | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 3600 | 2022-07-01 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 3600 | 2022-07-01 15:30:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 3600 | 2022-07-01 15:45:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 3600 | 2022-07-01 15:55:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 3300 | 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 3300 | 2022-07-01 15:25:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 3300 | 2022-07-01 15:40:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 3300 | 2022-07-01 15:50:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 3000 | 2022-07-01 14:50:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 3000 | 2022-07-01 15:20:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 3000 | 2022-07-01 15:35:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 3000 | 2022-07-01 15:45:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 2700 | 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 2700 | 2022-07-01 15:15:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 2700 | 2022-07-01 15:30:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 2700 | 2022-07-01 15:40:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 2400 | 2022-07-01 14:40:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 2400 | 2022-07-01 15:10:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 2400 | 2022-07-01 15:25:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 2400 | 2022-07-01 15:35:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 2100 | 2022-07-01 14:35:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 2100 | 2022-07-01 15:05:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 2100 | 2022-07-01 15:20:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 2100 | 2022-07-01 15:30:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 1800 | 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 1800 | 2022-07-01 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 1800 | 2022-07-01 15:15:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 1800 | 2022-07-01 15:25:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 1500 | 2022-07-01 14:25:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 1500 | 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 1500 | 2022-07-01 15:10:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 1500 | 2022-07-01 15:20:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 1200 | 2022-07-01 14:20:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 1200 | 2022-07-01 14:50:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 1200 | 2022-07-01 15:05:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 1200 | 2022-07-01 15:15:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 900 | 2022-07-01 14:15:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 900 | 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 900 | 2022-07-01 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 900 | 2022-07-01 15:10:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 600 | 2022-07-01 14:10:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 600 | 2022-07-01 14:40:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 600 | 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 600 | 2022-07-01 15:05:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 300 | 2022-07-01 14:05:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 300 | 2022-07-01 14:35:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 300 | 2022-07-01 14:50:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 300 | 2022-07-01 15:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 0 | 2022-07-01 14:00:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 0 | 2022-07-01 14:30:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 0 | 2022-07-01 14:45:00 | 0 |
| 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 0 | 2022-07-01 14:55:00 | 0 |

Comment: First of all - huge +1 for an elaborated answer and kick-ass example. I assure you, despite your uncertainty, that the illustration was badly needed. I guess you gravely overestimate my intellectual capacity to grasp the concept. But finally, it sunk in. (I actually suspected it was something like that but made the mistake of assuming that re-running for 60+ seconds would get me back to zero again. If I'd re-run for 60+ minutes, then it would!)

Comment: Oh, as for reading the docs - I did. You're confusing *reading* and *understanding*, let alone *realizing the implications*. Hence, the laboratory exercise to confirm. One thing I don't get still is that you used `datetime` while one of the comments suggests it's deprecated in the favor of `datetime2`. I get that it's not relevant to the problem presented but as long as we're poking around, is there a reason you went without the suffixed *2*?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yeah sorry, yours was the last of a few frustrating answers late at night ;) It could have done with less venom, i forget that I'm now accustomed to understanding the MS docs. But the message is important. We don't need to "test" or "experiment" to prove these concepts, we are not inventing anything new here. Doing so when we don't understand often leads us to the wrong conclusions. Rounding in this case. You are however right to reach out for help, if your test was written correctly, so NOT using `GetDate()`, then you would have picked this up pretty quickly.

Comment: I've updated the post after a good night's sleep ;) This probably helps the most: _Effectively this is a **Floor**, but the original values are **floored** first, before the comparison. There is no **rounding** or **floor** of the total time between the two values because the previous truncation reduces this to integer evaluation._

Comment: Great. And I'm mostly happy to heave understood it, eventually. One thing I noticed was that you used `datetime` as type. One of the commenters provided a [link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) saying that it's discouraged (instead, `datetime2` is recommended). What's your view on that?

Comment: My view is that you _should_ be using `DateTimeOffset`! `DateTime` has not actually been _deprecated_ (though I would support that), but since 2008 MS have strongly encouraged us to use `Date` for arbitrary dates like _DOB_ and `DateTimeOffset` for compatibility with javascript `date` objects... So for cloud and web workloads. The reality of `DateTime2` vs `DateTime` for this demo is that it makes no difference, we have no need for zero dates for this proof. `DATEDIFF` handles these date types the same way. It was not a helpful comment for this discussion, but rather a _red herring_.